# How to print python print function's output array in a straight line

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

```
'name': 'testfail2222',
'tags': ['customer:google',
         'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1',
         'check_type:api',
         'check_status:paused',
         'ci_execution_rule:non_blocking'],
```

Above is the output of python print function, but i want this to be print in a single line

```
'name': 'testfail2222',  
'tags':  ['customer:google','probe_dc:aws:us-west-1','check_type:api','check_status:paused','ci_execution_rule:non_blocking'],
```

I am saving the output of print function to a file then i am formatting as requirement.

```py
import os, json, re, sys
from itertools import islice
from datadog_api_client import ApiClient, Configuration
from datadog_api_client.v1.api.monitors_api import MonitorsApi

configuration = Configuration()
with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = MonitorsApi(api_client)
    response = api_instance.list_monitors(
            monitor_tags="check_status:paused"
    )

    sourceFile = open('printoutput.json', 'w')
    print(response, file = sourceFile)
    sourceFile.close()

    with open('printoutput.json', "r") as input:
            with open("temp.json", "w") as output:
            # iterate all lines from file
            for line in input:
                # if substring contain in a line then don't write it
                if "            'name': '" not in line.strip("\n"):
                    output.write(line)

    # replace file with original name
    os.replace('temp.json', 'printoutput.json')

    patrn = "'tags': [[\^[]]*]"
    word= "'name': "
    with open('printoutput.json','r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if word in line:
                print(line,  end="", flush=True)
            if re.search(patrn, line):
                print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Do you basically want to write out `response` into a file named `printoutput.json` as JSON? Note your current implementation does not produce valid JSON, `print` prints the result of calling `__str__` on an object and has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: i want to print 'tags' array in a single line not multiple line

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json` module to save it in proper format. I assume you want to save response to a file in JSON format.

```py
import json

with open('output.json'. 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(response))
```

Note: If you have unicode characters in the response use `json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False)`.

---

I think what you expect is the following. But this is rather unusual way to process a response. If possible try to process the response text itself.

```py
preformat = lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, list) else f"'{x}'"

# assuming you are printing a `dict` in very beginning of the question.
response = {
    'name': 'testfail2222',
    'tags': ['customer:google',
             'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1',
             'check_type:api',
             'check_status:paused',
             'ci_execution_rule:non_blocking'],
}

for k,v in response.items():
    print(f"'{k}': {preformat(v)},")

# output
'name': 'testfail2222',
'tags': ['customer:google', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'check_type:api', 'check_status:paused', 'ci_execution_rule:non_blocking'],
```

Answer (score 0):

As Indika said, better stick to json module.
For your case, usually things are not in any way pretty printed, so not sure if those line breaks are already added from api_instance.list_monitors(...

please do a

```
print(response)
```

to see/show what content is in it, if it is dict/json or already a multiline string.

If those line breaks already exist there, then try to modify the used implementation or call with other parameters.

Otherwise you can do a workaround by post-processing the content with some rules like..

```
fixed_response_list = []
tmp_long_line = ""
for line in response:
    if line.startswith(" "):
        tmp_long_line += " " + line.strip()
    else:
        if tmp_long_line:
            fixed_response_list.append(tmp_long_line)
        tmp_long_line = line
if tmp_long_line:
    fixed_response_list.append(tmp_long_line)
fixed_response_str = "\n".join(fixed_response_list)
```

Comment: have added image link in your answer's top

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the JSON in the way that you have asked, you can parse it into a Python Dict and print each key value.

```py
import json
with open('printoutput.json','r') as file:
    output = json.loads(file)
    for (k, v) in output.items():
        print(f'{k}: {v}')
```